# Creating hash from an array of values in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

I want to use each item in the array as values in a hash with the same key "name".

`people = ["Bob", "Mary", "Sarah", "Tim", "Maggie"]`

I want to get:

`{ name: => "Bob", name: => "Mary", name: => "Sarah", name: => "Tim", name: => "Maggie"}`

When I do `Hash[people.map {|v| ["name", v]}]` or

`people.map{|v| hash['name'] = v}`

it zips only the last item so I get this as a result :

```
{"name"=>"Maggie"}
```

Comment: What do you expect `hash[:name]` to return, in the hypothetical world where it were possible to have a key map to multiple values?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. Keys in a hash cannot be duplicated. Each key may only exist once, and map to exactly one value.